# MSVC++ uses base operator = overload for lvalue rather than rvalue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue

Here's the compiler splash screen (for version etc.):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>cl.exe
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
```

I have a base class (which is a template), imagine it's:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {

    public:

        Base<T> & operator = (const Base<T> &);
        Base<T> & operator = (Base<T> &&);

};
```

I then have a derived class which doesn't reimplement `operator =` in any way.

If I do the following:

```
Derived<int> derived;
derived=Derived<int>();
```

the `operator =` which accepts an lvalue is called on the second line.

If I go into the definition of `Derived<T>` and add the following:

```
template <typename T>
Derived<T> & Derived<T>::operator = (Derived<T> && other) {

    Base<T>::operator=(static_cast<Base<T> &&>(other));

    return *this;

}
```

The `operator =` which accepts an rvalue is called.

This behaviour persists even if I also implement the `operator =` which takes an lvalue (in much the same manner).

For lack of a better phrase: What gives?

Am I misunderstanding C++ or is this not how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MSVC never generates implicit move construction/assignment**. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293668.aspx .

The reason is that implicit move semantics have undergone many changes during standard elaboration, and the final consensus was not here at the time MSVC10 was finished.

Bottom line: you have to declare explicitly every move constructor / move assignment operator you'd like to use by hand. There is no `= default` modifier to help you. This means writing a lot of `swap` member functions, or simply give up on move semantics unless you 1) really need them (non copyable classes) or 2) have profiled your code and need to get rid of copies.

Default copy assignment is generated implicitly, and this is what you get here.

Answer (score 2):

Summary: You'll just have to manually define the move assignment operator you want until VS is updated with more complete C++11 support.

---

Since you don't declare a copy or move assignment operator the compiler may implicitly declare and define them for you. These default implementations then use the base classes copy and move assignment operators to copy or move the base class sub-object.

However the implicit declaration of a move assignment operator is suppressed in a number of circumstances, such as if the class has a user-declared copy-ctor, move-ctor, copy-assignment operator, or dtor. If your class has any of those then you don't automatically get a move assignment operator. *[**Edit:** And Alexandre C. points out that VS2010 will never implicitly declare move assignment operators or ctors anyway.]*

Without a move assignment operator `derived=Derived<int>();` calls the implicitly declared/defined copy assignment operator, which calls the copy assignment operator for `Base<T>`, and `Base<T>::operator = (Base<T> &&)` is not called.

If you want the default definition for the move assignment operator even though you also need to do one of the things that suppresses its implicit declaration you could use the new `= default` syntax (although there was a defect in the standard that would mean in some cases `= default` wouldn't actually get you the default definition, but it's been resolved), however VS10 doesn't support `= default`. You'll just have to manually define the move assignment operator you want until VS is updated with more complete C++11 support.

I think with full C++11 support it's a good idea not to rely on implicit declarations, and those special member functions which can be implicitly declared should always be declared explicitly (as `= delete` if you don't want one generated). The implicit declarations were originally done for backward compatibility with C. Explicit declarations are easier to understand and have no drawbacks now that C++11 adds `= default`.

Comment: MSVC10 does not support implicit move construction / assignment in any form.

Comment: Does the version of GCC available for Windows via MinGW?

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy:  g++ 4.7 will implicitly generate move operations and can be used under MinGW on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Standart (3337, 12.8.24). [standart](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)
If we type using Base::operator =; Base::operator =(Base&&) will be used.

Comment: I understand rvalues vs. lvalues, my point is that in the code snippet I gave -- in `derived=Derived<int>();` -- an rvalue is present, therefore the rvalue version of `Base<T>::operator=` should be called (given that no `operator=` is implemented on `Derived<T>`), but it's not, the lvalue version is.

Answer (score 1):

The move constructor of `Base<int>` should be called in this case, so long as `Derived<T>` does not have any user-declared copy operations, move operations, or a user-declared destructor.  `Derived<T>` has an implicitly-declared move assignment operator that will move base class subobjects, including its `Base<T>` base class subobject.

However, Visual C++ (as of Visual C++ 2012 RC) does not implicitly generate move operations, thus you see that a copy is performed instead of a move.  If you want to aggregate or derive from movable types, and want the aggregating or derived type to be moveable, you must define your own move constructor and move assignment operator.

The specification of move operations and the circumstances under which they are implicitly declared changed several times during the last two years of standardization.  It wasn't until February 2010 that implicit declaration of move operations was added to C++11 (i.e., it changed after Visual C++ 2010 was completed).  The specification then changed several times after that before C++11 was completed last year, and the changes were rather contentious.

Visual C++ 2012 also does not implicitly generate move operations.